# Show the following integral for non-negative X and Y

Tags: probability, integration, bivariate-distributions

Completely stuck on this problem.

Let X and Y be non-negative random variables with an arbitrary joint probability distribution function. Let $$I(x,y)=\begin{cases}1,\quad if \:X>x,\:Y>y\\0,\quad otherwise\end{cases}$$Show that $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty I(x,y)dxdy=XY$$
It seems to me that $I(x,y)$ is an indicator variable (Bernoulli?) with probability of success $\mathbb P((X,Y)>(x,y))$. Then the integral is sort of summing over the real plane for all the ordered pairs that give $1$. Thus the integral should evaluate to the area of total region in $R^2$ where those $(x,y)$ are less than $X,Y$. But I have no idea if that's correct, or how to formally go about this, and honestly it feels like I'm floundering here...

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty I(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^Y\int_0^X \,dx\,dy$

Comment: Wow.. that is amazingly simple...thanks!